# Image Halftone in C# and SIlverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, image-processing

How can we make a halftone effect for a image in silverlight using C#.
Please help..
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First should be the algorithm itself:
[Algorithm to make halftone images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258047/algorithm-to-make-halftone-images)
Or google..

Then you should use [WritableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.95).aspx) to read input image and write output image. You might need to get some helper class to make reading and writing easier and more intuitive.