# Creating a color halftone effect for images using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

Would anyone be able to tell me if there is a way to apply a color halftone effect to an image using JavaScript and without using WebGL. I need to create it so it can be used across multiple devices and browsers. I have found this but its using WebGL: http://evanw.github.com/webgl-filter/

Would I be able to use three.js or processing.js to achieve it?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069171/canvas-change-colors-of-an-image-using-html5-css-js

Answer (score 2):

1. Create yourself a canvas element and put the image inside (see link from @Diodeus).
2. Get the image data from the canvas - now you can iterate over all pixels.
3. Apply the halftone filter on the image data. see: [Algorithm to make halftone images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258047/algorithm-to-make-halftone-images)
4. Update image data

BTW: I don't recomment to do this on the client machine. Image Processing requires some processing power which may not be available on the client (e.g. Smartphone). Better do it ONCE on the server with e.g. ImageMagick.