# Approximating image using similar non-overlapping circles

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, approximation, dithering

I am trying to find an algorithm that would approximate a greyscale image using an appropriate number of mathematical shapes from a predefined set of shapes which can be used (3 differently sized circles in my case).

I have considered error diffusion based algorithms such as Floyd-Steinberg algorithm, but I can't see a way to translate pixel-based error diffusion to mathematical shapes.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Edit:
Here's an example using squares instead of circles
[image: An example with squares instead of circles]
Another example using uniformly sized circles on a grid instead. This was produced by replacing dithered squares with circles, but this yielded poor results due to deviation from the originally approximated image. The circles here are distributed in a grid, which is not what I am looking for:
[image]

Comment: Surely you have an example or two? And some indication of your motivation? And what is a *"similar circle"* please? Similar to what?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [halftoning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258047/algorithm-to-make-halftone-images)?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I added a couple examples that come close to what I want. I can't show you an example of what *exactly* I want, because I do not know how to produce such an image, hence this post. By a *"similar"* circle, I mean, a circle which is similarly sized to other circles within a set (say 25% size variance). My motivation is a long story, but in short, these circles would be printed over plastic sheet and drilled in, to form a representation of an image, which is why it must be circles and why they need to approximate an image.

Comment: @beaker Not quite - take a look at the examples I added.

Comment: Ah, then I'd look at stippling algorithms. Although there will always be some degree of regularity in automatically-generated patterns.

Comment: @beaker Yes, that is exactly it, thank you so much!

Comment: Both your examples seem to be error diffusion at work. The dots are on a grid.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The principle of Floyd-Steinberg is to estimate the local error between the original image and the binary one. As every pixel is replaced by a wrong value, the error is remembered and used as a compensation to evaluate the next pixel.

Your case is more difficult because of the variable pitch, requiring some collision-avoidance strategy. The generalization of error diffusion would be to fill the image in a semi-regular way with the desired shapes and estimate the averaged grayscale equivalent. Then place a shape at the next empty slot when the discrepancy becomes large enough.

Easier said than done.